# Can we use Gmail Api service account for reset password service in a asp.net core web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, gmail-api

How to use service account for a "reset password service" in a asp.net core 3.1 web application. I know how to send an email through service account. I am not sure if this thing is safe and right for using in a reset password service. Will it work?
[I cannot test it in the real project before testing it independently]